# JBoss: can not connect to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, jboss7.x, mysql-connector

I am running `JBoss` as standalone version. I would like to connect to my local `mysql database`

I copied the mysql connector in modules folder

```
me@air~/Downloads/jboss/standalone/configuration - 10:56:18  $ ls ../../modules/org/mysql/main/
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
```

Next I changed the `standalone.xml` in `jboss/standalone/configuration` as

```
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="com.mysql" module="org.mysql" />
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2"> <!-- default provided-->
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

Then I added the datasource as

```
              <datasource jndi-name="java:/bb" pool-name="bb-pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>bb</user-name>
                        <password>bb</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

I am using `JBoss AS 7.1`.
When I start the server on console, I see errors

```
10:54:47,458 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:54:47,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/bb] 

10:54:47,676 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:54:47,676 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 2000ms - Started 134 of 212 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

and when I hit `Ctrl+C`, I see

```
^C10:54:54,998 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
10:54:55,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
10:54:55,007 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
10:54:55,008 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
10:54:55,010 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
10:54:55,039 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:54:55,039 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:54:55,043 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql (new available)

10:54:55,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 47ms
```

I am new to JBoss and don't know how to fix this issue or to understand what is that I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

I think in your datasource you are referencing the driver `mysql`, but you named the driver `com.mysql`.

Try changing one the driver name to `mysql`.

Just a note: it is best to use the CLI to install the drivers and use the CLI or Web Console to build your datasources.  The intention with AS7 is that these tools are used for all of your config and there are very few reasons why you should touch the XML yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your driver definition name doesn't match the driver name under the `<datasource>` definition. Replace `<driver name="com.mysql" ...` with `<driver name="mysql" ...` for it to work.

Second, have you added the `module.xml` file? It's not enough to copy the MySQL connector jar in the `./modules/com/mysql/main` folder, you also have to add the `module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also, I had a strage similar problem when using the MySQL connector version 5.0.8, where the driver was not found / recognized. It disappeared when I switched to the newer 5.1.26 version.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same mistake. Took me hours to find out how dumb it was.

In my case I was running jboss as a service under the jboss-as user, nice and easy. Except that when I created the mysql/main directory, along with the files within, I was under another user. No permissions there for jboss-as guy.

A simple chown on modules/ directory did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using latest version of `mysql jdbc connector` , i solve same issue of mine with replacing latest mysql connetor